# Animation in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

I have been trying to implement the animation feature in my web page. I initially tried to implement the animation in Jquery and it worked but it doesn't appear as desired. The following code is just an example of my actual implementation. So, here I have a well which has a table inside it. I am moving the table to the left and right on the click of buttons "Slide Left " and "Slide Right" respectively. As you can notice from the code, I have used .hide() because I want the content to be moved out of the page and show "slide right" animation on click of "Slide Right " button and then remove the content. If I don't use the .hide() property, it will cause my webpage to be horizontally scroll-able which is not desired. Also, in my actual implementation, I want to replace the current table with another table and do this by showing the animation effect. I got a suggestion that this can be done as desired using Angular js , but me being a novice, I have been struggling to write Angular version of my code. How can I achieve the desired functionality using Angular animation? I hope it's something simple and easy to understand. 
Code can be found here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideRightButton").click(function(){
        $("#boxToBeMoved").animate({left: '+=99%'}, "slow");
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#boxToBeMoved").hide(); }, 500);

    });
    $("#slideLeftButton").click(function(){
        $("#boxToBeMoved").animate({left: '-=99%'}, "slow");
         $("#boxToBeMoved").show(); 
    });

});
</script> 
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container">
  <h2><button id="slideRightButton">Slide Right</button>
<button id="slideLeftButton">Slide Left</button></h2>

  <div class="well">
  <div id="boxToBeMoved" style="position:relative;">
  <table> <tr><th>Heading </th></tr> <tr><td>Data1</td></tr> </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```